# Выгрузить данные с определенными значениями

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Необходимо выгрузить список пользователей, у которых проходили несколько операций. 
Каждая операция в базе записана несколько раз, но с разным значением в столбце "code". Нужно выгрузить те операции, по которым значение в столбце "code" содержало и 'ok' и 'resp'в разное время. Прошу помочь сделать правильный запрос, т.к. когда я делаю IN ('ok' AND 'resp') у меня выгружается список только с 'ok'. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: *когда я делаю IN ('ok' AND 'resp') у меня выгружается список только с 'ok'.* Потому что этого мало. Надо ещё сгруппировать и проверить, что количество разных значений равно двум. RTFM "реляционное деление".

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, сгруппировать можно по операциям? Чтобы отображались операции со всеми значениями в 'code' поочередно?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT {список полей вывода}
FROM {таблица(ы)-источник(и)}
WHERE {поле} IN ( {набор значений, через запятую} )
GROUP BY {список полей вывода}
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT {поле} ) = {количество уникальных значений в наборе}
```